React native does not start application, Android Studio Windows 11
I am new to react native with Android studio. I have configuration in my system like this:
node = v20.16.0
npm = 10.8.1
java = java 17.0.12 2024-07-16 LTS
Chocolaty =  v2.2.2

I am creating react native application using this cmd  npx @react-native-community/cli init
After creating an application, to start the project I used cmd npm start.
It is trying to start the application, the emulator is opening, but I get an error due to that project is not loading in emulator.
Please help to resolve this issue.
Thanks
This is the error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'ndefinedndefined'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.6.0.
Required by:
root project :
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.6.0.
Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.6.0/gradle-8.6.0.pom'.
Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/8.6.0/gradle-8.6.0.pom'.
Got SSL handshake exception during request. It might be caused by SSL misconfiguration
PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 16s


